# how to send same payload to multiple component in mule?

Tags: java, spring, mule, mule-studio

I have a problem where  one mule component transform the payload object into some other value. Ex: Suppose my payload contain student object.
Initial value of Student name=a;

My first mule component change student name to x;

```
Student s=new Student();
s.setName("x");
```

My second mule component receive name as `X` from payload. But I want original value as `'a'`.
I tried checking original payload of mule but that value is also changed..

```
<flow .....
   <component> </component> // 1st component
    <component></component> //2nd component
</flow>
```

I want same payload(original) (Student object with name a) in both the component..how can I do that?
I have checked original payload and that has been transformed..

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<all>` to send same payload to different components like

```
<flow .....
   <all>
       <component> </component> // 1st component
       <component></component> //2nd component
   </all>
</flow>
```

or, a different way to approach same thing is to store the original payload in a variable and then replace the payload with the previous one like:

```
<set-variable variableName="originalPayload" value="#[message.payload]" />
```

and then,

```
<set-payload value="#[flowVars.originalPayload]"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Mule also use `scatter gather` component, which sends the payload to multiple endpoints in parallel. This component has been introduced from Mule 3.5.0 .. 
example :

```
<scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather" timeout="6000">
 <flow-ref name="flightBroker1" />
 <flow-ref name="flightBroker2" />
 <flow-ref name="flightBroker3" />
</scatter-gather>
```

Here is the reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Scatter-Gather